# Limit of integral of probability density function

Tags: limits

Is $\lim_{x \to 0} \int_{0}^{x}f(z) f_{A}(x-z)dz = 0$? Here $f(.)$, $f_{A}(.)$ are probability density functions. How do you prove this ?

Comment: This is true for any integrable functions $f,f_A$.

Comment: Does the above logic extend to double integrals too i.e. $\lim_{x \to 0} \int_{0}^{x}f(x-y)\{\int_{0}^{y}f(z) f_{A}(y-z)dz\}dy = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

This is true for any integrable function $f$.  Consider arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$ and the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^{\varepsilon}{fdx}$.  Then, assuming $f$ has a max $m$ the integral is bound by $$m\varepsilon\geq\int_{0}^{\varepsilon}{f(x)dx}$$ and by letting $\varepsilon\rightarrow0$ obviously the value of the integral goes to $0$.  This can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$ pretty simply.  Here you have multiple bounds, but considering the integral with fixed upper bounds $a_i$ together with a variable upper bound $\varepsilon$, the bound on the integral is $$m\varepsilon\prod_i{a_i}\geq\int_0^{a_1}\!\!\!\int_0^{a_2}\cdots\int_0^{a_{n-1}}\!\!\!\int_0^{\varepsilon}{f(x)dx}$$ and the bound can still be brought to $0$ by letting $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$.  This is the same argument as the M-L inequality in complex analysis (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma), and I hope this helps.

Comment: Why does an integrable function have a max?

Comment: To be Riemann integrable a function must be bounded and be continuous a.e.  This was formulated by Lebesgue and is called the Lebesgue integrability criterion.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability.

Comment: Yes, but who said "Riemann integrable"?

Comment: Well it's not even true that $\int_{0}^{0}fd\mu=0$ for the Lebesgue integral: consider the "stupid" measure where $\mu(A)=\infty$ unless $A=\emptyset$, and $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.  Then the integral $\int_{\{0\}}d\mu=\infty$